# G++ linking - Link only used symbols

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries, ld, dynamic-linking

I have a problem when linking c++ code with g++. I have two files : `file1` and `file2`:

```
file1:

int A(){
   return B();
}

int C(){
   return 0;
}
```

```
file2:

int B(){
   return 4;
}
```

I am building a shared library that uses `C()` function so I only compile with `file1` and not `file2`. I don't have problems when compiling or linking, but when I use the shared library, I receive an error at execution saying that `B` is not defined.

If I compile and link with `file2` I do not have problem. But I don't want this solution, because I have multiple recursive inclusions.

I have tried to compile with `--ffunctions-sections` and `--fdata-sections` and then link with `-Wl,--gc-sections` but it did not solved my problem.

Is there a way to link only the symbols (here functions) that I actually use ?

Answer (score 0):

You should think of shared libraries as of something universal. Even if you want to borrow always one book from the library, others might want to borrow other books. Therefore either remove the method `int A()` or make it work by linking to its dependency.

G++ offers link-time optimization (with parameter `-flto` while compiling and linking). But making the method `int A()` unreachable and then hoping that it gets optimized away is definitely not a clean solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks. So it appears that what I wished to do is actually not possible. In fact, I am building multiple shared libraries and some of them use common functions. That is why I wanted to optimized my code and not duplicate it by compiling with a file even if not all the functions where actually used. So I think, after what you've said, that the proper solution is to re-think my files architecture. So it is what I am going to do.

Comment: A good architecture is always important! And get rid of methods that **nobody** ever uses. But having methods and classes in a library that are used only by **some** libraries or applications is not a bad design.